# Deploy web app using Elastic Beantalk without auto-scaling

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I'm trying to deploy a node.js application into aws using Elastic BeansTalk. However, while creating a web server environment, it fails because my account does not havve the permission to use auto scaling due to cost. Is there a way to disable autoscaling completely with elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Have you access to the Elastic Beanstalk console? Or maybe the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just create a single instance environment.

As per the AWS docs, single instance environments do not have load balancers or auto-scaling.  You can read more about Elastic Beanstalk environment types here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html?ref_=pe_395030_31184250_9